# Ice cream stabilizer - ratio of components

Tags: ice-cream, stabilizers

My husband and I are very much into creating the perfect keto/sugar free ice cream. He has gotten right into the nitty gritty science of it but still wants to tweak a few things.

We have purchased an emulsifier so that can stay out of this equation for now, I am just inquiring about stabilizers. We know we want to make a blend of stabilizers (which include CMC & Locust Bean or Guar Gum & Carrageenan). Since we can't find this specific blend for sale pre-made we would like to buy the individual ingredients and mix it ourselves. We know the ratio of stabilizers to other ingredients in the overall ice cream mix, however we don't know the ratio of each mentioned ingredient in the stabilizer blend itself.

Can anyone help shed some light here?

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/68959/gms-and-cmc-ratios-in-ice-cream

Answer (score 2):

I generally use locust bean gum : guar gum : carrageenan in ice cream with the following ratio: 4:2:1

Comment: That's pretty much in line with Underbelly's standard mix: 0.8g of LBG, 0.4g of GG, and 0.2g of lambda carrageenan per liter of mix.